# Sending hexadecimal or ASCII value stored in a variable using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, hex, ascii, pyserial

I was trying to send a byte containing hex value over serial port using pyserial. The hex value has to be in a variable (so that I can do some manipulations before sending). Sample code will explain my intent:

```
import serial  
com=serial.Serial('COM1')  
a_var=64
a_var=a_var+1
com.write(a_var)  #This of course throws error
```

I want to receive 'A' or 0x41 on the other side. I could send hex using

```
    com.write(b'\x41')
```

but not using a variable. Converting it to string or character or encoding the string did not help. I am using python 3.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bytearray can be used to send bytes (as hex or ascii). They are mutable, hence numerical manipulations are possible. Any number of bytes can be sent using it.

```
import serial

com=serial.Serial('COM2')
elements=[65,67,69,71]      #Create an array of your choice
a_var=bytearray(elements)   #Create byte array of it
com.write(a_var[0:3])       #Write desired elements at serial port

a_var[0]=a_var[0]+1         #Do your mathematical manipulation

com.write(a_var[0:1])       #Write again as desired
com.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

At first the name choice of your variable was not optimal. `input` is a built-in function and you might shadow it.

There are many way to put `bytes` into a variable:

```
to_send = b'A'
to_send = b'\x41'
to_send = bytes([65])
```

You see how to use an ASCII character, the escape sequence for hex numbers and the list of integers.

Now send via

```
com.write(to_send)
```

Comment: This variable name was just an example. I had used another. Anyways, I will edit it.

Comment: But this does not serve the purpose of having a variable. I want to do some addition and subtraction on the data before sending. However bytearray([x]) did the trick. It is mutable. I changed values at index 0.